# Raster Calculator in QGIS does not calculate the entire layer

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I am working with two raster layers from [WorldClim](http://worldclim.org/version2), using max temperature and minimum t. I want to obtain the range, meaning, doing tmax minus tmin. When I use raster calculator in order to do so, the result is a really small area.

The original raster 
[image: entire world raster]

When I substract one raster layer with another (both of the same source, size, SRC, just different band values), this is the result:

[image]

How do I obtain the difference for the entire raster, and not just that small part?

Comment: going by the layer names, they seem to be different resolutions (5 minutes/pixel and 10 minutes/pixel), have you tried using two of the same resolution?

Comment: Yes, and I still have the same cropped area. I was trying to see how the calculator was working by using different pixel size but using equal or different resolutions provides that small area as a result.

Comment: What settings do you have in your Result layer box in the raster calculator? There are settings for Xmin, Xmax, Ymin and Ymax. Perhaps you should check that so that they are the same as your input layers.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the data and did a try, everything seems to work:

[image: raster calculator:]

map canvas:
[image: screenshot map canvas]